# What is wrong with this javascript code? The return is wrong

Tags: javascript

```
var number = prompt('Enter Number (as long as you want): '),
    output = [],
    sNumber = number.toString(),
    lastDigit,
    result,
    i;

function result(number) {
    for (i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    lastDigit = output.slice(-1);

    switch (lastDigit[0]) {
        case 0:
            return 'zero';
            break;
        case 1:
            return 'one';
            break;
            .....etc some more cases.......
            default: return 'not a valid number';
            break;
    }
}
jsConsole.writeLine('Last digit in English: ' + result);
```

Why the results ended with all the code but not one of the switch cases? I have struggled to get it fixed. I just want the result in the switch case to be printed.

Comment: The number entered will be a string. I don't see where your converting it to a number for use by the switch. Try parseInt(lastDigit[0]) as your switch condition.

Comment: Is `result` a function or a variable? Don't mix declaration names.

Comment: To expand on what @MaxArt said, you should rename your `result` variable to something else.

Comment: Also as @JonEdwards says , change `switch (lastDigit[0]) {` to `switch (parseInt(lastDigit[0])) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not actually calling the result function
2. Don't name functions and variables the same
3. If you have a `number` parameter then use it, don't use global variables
4. You don't need `break` if you have `return`
5. `prompt` will return a string, so no need for `toString()` on it

Like this:

```
var sNumber = prompt('Enter Number (as long as you want): ');

function result(number) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i ++) {
        output.push(+number.charAt(i));
    }
    var lastDigit = output.slice(-1);

    switch (lastDigit[0]) {
        case 0:
            return 'zero';
        case 1:
            return 'one';
        default: 
            return 'not a valid number';
    }
}

jsConsole.writeLine('Last digit in English: ' + result(sNumber));
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/12un1egk/)

---

For your information, you can get the last character of a string without a loop:

```
var lastDigit = number[number.length-1]; 
// assuming it will always have at least 1 character, add validation to be sure
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling result.

To call result you should do:

```
result()
```

Without parentheses you are meaning the value of result which in fact is a function.

If you also concatenate it to some string, type coercion make you to end up with the same as you were did:

```
jsConsole.writeLine('Last digit in English: ' + result.toString());
```